# Giving Comomn crawl location as input to Amazon EMR using mrjob python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, emr, mrjob, common-crawl

It has been only days since I started using mrjob and I have tried certain low and medium level tasks.Now I am stuck at giving Common crawl `[now onwards will be know as CC]` location as input to emr using python mrjob

**My config file looks like this :**

```
runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: <AWS Access Key>
    aws_secret_access_key: <AWS Secret Access Key>
    aws_region: us-east-1
    ec2_key_pair: cslab
    ec2_key_pair_file: ~/cslab.pem
    ec2_instance_type: m1.small
    num_ec2_instances: 5
  local:
    base_tmp_dir: /tmp
```

`Big thing small :I am trying to get the number of words in a web page of a site`

`Big thing big: Is my code below`

**My Code:**

```
import warc

class MRcount(MRJob):
    # ...

    def mapper(self, _, s3_path):
        s3_url_parsed = urlparse.urlparse(s3_url)
        bucket_name = s3_url_parsed.netloc
        key_path = s3_url_parsed.path[1:]
        conn = boto.connect_s3()
        bucket = conn.get_bucket('aws-publicdatasets', validate=False)
        key = Key(bucket, s3_path)
        webpage_text = record.payload.read()
        yield record.header['warc-target-uri'],len(webpage_text.split()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRcount.run())
```

Everything is good till now but when I try to run it .

**Cmd:**

```
$ python mr_crawl.py -r emr s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2014-52/wet.paths.gz
```

**Error:**

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message <RequestId>06660583263444FC</RequestId><Bucket>smarkets-db</Bucket><HostId>TCZJTKZ8wo8V1h0xjkOI6grojs/r9IBkhMOcvolXv06QEtxTX89M55aLTPGOo/ht</HostId><Endpoint>eu-west-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint></Error>
```

I thought it was because of the region in my config file and removed it but I get a new error

**My new config file:**

```
runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: <AWS Access Key>
    aws_secret_access_key: <AWS Secret Access Key>
    ec2_key_pair: cslab
    ec2_key_pair_file: ~/cslab.pem
    ec2_instance_type: m1.small
    num_ec2_instances: 5
  local:
    base_tmp_dir: /tmp
```

**I get the following error SSH error:**

```
using configs in /etc/mrjob.conf
using existing scratch bucket mrjob-4db6342a70e021ad
using s3://mrjob-4db6342a70e021ad/tmp/ as our scratch dir on S3
creating tmp directory /tmp/word_count.20140603.181541.006786
writing master bootstrap script to /tmp/word_count.20140603.181541.006786/b.py
Copying non-input files into s3://mrjob-4db6342a70e021ad/tmp/word_count.matthew.20140603.181541.006786/files/
Waiting 5.0s for S3 eventual consistency
Creating Elastic MapReduce job flow
Job flow created with ID: j-3DCN7LULSRILW
Created new job flow j-3DCN7LULSRILW
Job on job flow j-3DCN7LULSRILW failed with status FAILED: The given SSH key name was invalid
Logs are in s3://mrjob-4db6342a70e021ad/tmp/logs/j-3DCN7LULSRILW/
Scanning S3 logs for probable cause of failure
Waiting 5.0s for S3 eventual consistency
Terminating job flow: j-3DCN7LULSRILW
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word_count.py", line 16, in <module>
    MRcount.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 494, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 512, in execute
    super(MRJob, self).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 147, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 208, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 458, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/emr.py", line 809, in _run
    self._wait_for_job_to_complete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/emr.py", line 1599, in _wait_for_job_to_complete
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: Job on job flow j-3DCN7LULSRILW failed with status FAILED: The given SSH key name was invalid
```

Thanks ,

Comment: The name of the ssh-key must be the same as what is in your aws console.

Comment: @Pykler I haven't given an ssh-key in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you MrJob config you need to set the ec2_key_pair according to the list of keypairs in your aws console

```
runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: <AWS Access Key>
    aws_secret_access_key: <AWS Secret Access Key>
    ec2_key_pair: cslab # <---- this name doesnt exist inside aws, so aws doesnt know the public key to use
    ec2_key_pair_file: ~/cslab.pem # <-- you can comment this out if you dont need to login to the machine via ssh
    ec2_instance_type: m1.small
    num_ec2_instances: 5
  local:
    base_tmp_dir: /tmp
```

To see the list of key pairs you have inside aws, [see this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)